# Teamcity build all svn branches

Tags: svn, teamcity

In TeamCity, I would like to have one build configuration that picks up all branches in our SVN without having to manually specify them out.

Is it possible do this?

I've tried configuring the checkout rules with the following [wildcard](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Wildcards)

```
   +:branches/*
```

but the system seems to reject the [wildcard](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Wildcards) being there or doesn't know what to do with it.

Is it possible to checkout a HEAD revision in SVN irrespective of branch/tag/trunk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need checkout rules for that, just specify top-level URL as your VCS root in Version Control Settings.