# Teamcity build last svn checkin for any branch

Tags: git, svn, continuous-integration, teamcity

In TeamCity, I would like to have one build configuration that picks up the **last check in**, in any branch, in our SVN without having to manually specify them out.

If I set the VCS to the root of the SVN repository, it will checkout all tags, branches and trunk. Instead of building all the possible deviations, I would rather like to just build the last check-in itself. Is there a way to do this?

I tried to ask this question previously, which resulted in a correct response but not what not what I had originally intended. [Teamcity build all svn branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582129/teamcity-build-all-svn-branches)

Comment: What do you mean by you need to build just the last check-in. Let's say the last check-in has modification in just one file. So are you saying you need to build only that branch which has this check-in.

Comment: So you want to use the same Build Configuration for multiple branches?